# Handle onChange in a ReactJs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I currently have a React tsx page with some input boxes; for example:

```
<textarea value={this.state.myData!.valueOne}
    onChange={(e) => this.handleValueOneChange(e)}/>

<textarea value={this.state.myData!.valueTwo}
    onChange={(e) => this.handleValueTwoChange(e)}/>
```

`handleValueOneChange` and `handleValueTwoChange` look almost identical:

```
handleValueOneChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
    let newState = { ...this.state };

    newState.myData!.valueOne = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}

handleValueTwoChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
    let newState = { ...this.state };

    newState.myData!.valueTwo = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Is it possible to have a single function for both events; for example:

```
handleDataChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>, valueByRef) {
    let newState = { ...this.state };

    valueByRef = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

I'm a little unclear on what this might look like in TypeScript: is what I'm trying to do possible and, if so, how?

EDIT:

To further complicate matters myData contains a mix of types (which appears to be an issue for TS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

HTML becomes

```
<textarea value={this.state.myData!.valueOne}
    onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e, 'valueOne')}/>

<textarea value={this.state.myData!.valueTwo}
    onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e, 'valueTwo')}/>
```

and logic (I suppose your state has type MyState)

```
handleDataChange<K extends keyof MyDataType>(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>, ref: K) {
    let newState = { ...this.state };

    newState.myData![ref] = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

EDIT:

I fixed the answer according to the comments

EDIT:
If myData contains strings, numbers and booleans you can use type guards and casts

```
handleDataChange<K extends keyof MyDataType>(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>, ref: K) {
    let newState = { ...this.state };

    let old = newState.myData![ref];
    if (typeof old === "number") newState.myData![ref] = parseInt(event.currentTarget.value); /* or parseFloat, this depends on your app */
    else if (typeof old === "boolean") newState.myData![ref] = (event.currentTarget.value === "1"); /* use any string -> boolean conversion function */
    else newState.myData![ref] = event.currentTarget.value; /* string case */
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Comment: This gives the error: (TS) Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ myState: MyState; }[K]'.
  Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'MyState'. on handleDataChange.  I would guess this is because the properties are not directly on the state, but a property of a subtype MyData...?

Comment: @qwerty you are right, I should have updated the answer to account for that, let me know if this works

Comment: No - I tried that (and updated my question slightly).  The error I get there is "Type string is not assignable from number|undefined".  I assume it's because MyData contains strings, numeric and boolean data?

Comment: @qwerty event.currentTarget.value is always a string, if your property is of another type you have to cast it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Of course, pass a string back, for example:

```
<Input onChange={(event)=>this.handleChange(event, 'type1')} />
```

Comment: How would I then use that string to reference a property on the state?

Answer (score 0):

If you give your text area's a name prop, you can use this name to add the value to state.

```
handleChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state.myData,
      [event.currentTarget.name]: event.currentTarget.value,
    })
  }


<textarea value={this.state.myData.one} name="one"
   onChange={this.handleChange} />

<textarea value={this.state.myData.two} name="two"
   onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

`onChange` prop looks cleaner in this case too. No use of an inline arrow function.

Working Code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/04rm89oq8w

Comment: This gives me the error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'valueOne' does not exist in type 'Pick<MyState, "myData">'.  Also, the link here is dead